# past or future: later today

Tags: past-tense, time-words, time-reference

Can the phrase "later today" refer to the past as follows?

> A: When did you give John the document?
>
> B: Later today.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: No, it cannot. You did something earlier today, or you will do it later today.

Comment: As Kate says. **later that day** would refer to the past.

Comment: How about "later in the day"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One cannot use "later today" to mean "at a later time today that is already in the past. If the meaning  is "I gave it to him at a later time today" something like the following might be said:

> A: When did you give John the document?
>
> B: Today, but not this morning. I gave it to him later in the day, perhaps around 2 pm.

also possible would be:

> A: Did you give John the document Tuesday morning?
>
> B: No, later that day.

A comment by the OP asks:

> Does "later this year" behave like "later today" in the sense that it cannot refer to a time in the past?

I would say no. for example:

> A: When did you have the driveway re-paved?
>
> B: I had the windows replaced in February, and later this year -- perhaps in April -- I had the driveway done.

However, using  "later in the year" instead would be more common and sound more natural, IMO. I can't specify any rule for the difference. Maybe it is just that a year is so much longer a time than a day. If one treated it as a rule and never used "later this year" to refer to a time in the past, it would not harm one's English.

Comment: Does "later this year" behave like "later today" in the sense that it cannot refer to a time in the past?

Comment: @Apollyon I would say not. I will edit my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

"Did" is the *past tense* of the verb "to do", and here is being used to ask about the *past*.

> When did you give John the document?

In the answer you give, "later today" is in the *future*, so it seems wrong. *However* - if you mean to answer that you *didn't* give it to John yesterday, but you *will* do it today, that is fine - you just need to explain that, otherwise it makes no sense.

You could answer:

> I didn't give it him yesterday, but I *will* give it to him later today.

Or the more succinct:

> I will give it to him later today.

Comment: What if I mean to say I didn't give the document to John early in the morning but later?